# c++ cgi on linux server

Tags: c++, linux, windows, cgi

I am pretty new to CGI's and wanted to give them a try. Here is my situation:
My website is hosted on a linux server, I have contacted the hosting company and they said as long as I use the cgi-bin folder there is no problem. So I wrote a very short c++ program that just output some text:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
 cout << "Hello from c++ cgi";

 return 0;
}
```

Since its a linux server (and I am running Windows) I suppose I needed to compile the source in linux so a installed a virtual machine running Ubuntu. I then compiled the source (tested it in Ubuntu) and placed the binary file in the cgi-bin folder. Then I used a simple html anchor to link to it:

```
<a href="cgi-bin/cgiTest">T</a>
```

But when I click the link on my page I get the "500 Internal Server Error" message. I have also tried to rename the binary file to "cgiTest.cgi" and update the link but still the same problem.

Anybody have any idea where my problem lies?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the help, turns out I had to change the permissions and the hosting server is 32bit while I compiled on 64bit Ubuntu. I now compiled on 32bit Ubuntu and voila!, its running. Thanks to all for the help in solving this issue!

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to output any HTTP headers (the error log entry would give you a hint).

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
 cout << "Content-Type: text/plain" << endl << endl;
 cout << "Hello from c++ cgi";

 return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I have added the headers but still get the same problem. The error log reports that the "File does not exist" but it sure does and I have double checked the path, all looks good. I have also again mailed the hosting company with the same description of my problem.

Comment: Did you change the permissions of the file? CGI scripts need to be executable and not world-writable.